# Reinstalling Python 2.5.6 On Lion

Tags: python, google-app-engine, build, makefile, osx-lion

I am having the identical problem as mentioned in this thread when I try to install Python 2.5.6 on Lion: [Python 2.5.6 build error on Mac Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10084379/python-2-5-6-build-error-on-mac-lion)

Specifically, the error I receive is when attempting a make is:

```
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -c -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-long-double -no-cpp-precomp -mno-fused-madd -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE -o Modules/python.o ./Modules/python.c
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-long-double"
make: *** [Modules/python.o] Error 1
```

In my case, it is as a result of me deleting the python 2.5 folder thinking I would never need it while I was troubleshooting another problem.

Now, when I try to launch Google App Engine, I get the error: "Sorry, pieces of GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app appear missing or corrupted, or I can't run python2.5 properly" and then it shuts down, so unfortunately I can't just ignore the problem as is recommended in the previous thread.

EDIT:
It looks like I messed things up pretty royally by deleting the folder. The solution (though I haven't implemented it yet) is described here: [Mac Python "Installation step failed: run postflight script"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473762/mac-python-installation-step-failed-run-postflight-script)

EDIT x2:
Solved it! Though I have no idea what kind of damage I've done. I ran the .DMG installer, and even though it failed it placed the folder for Python 2.5.4. in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions`. I then copied that along with 2.7 into the `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions` folder. After that, launched Google App Engine and everything worked! (For now.)

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried installing Python 2.5 yourself? How, and how did it turn out?

Comment: Hi Kenneth, yes, as mentioned above I tried installing Python 2.5.6 using the source code from here http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.5.6/ using "make" and "make install" but received the errors mentioned in the above link. I'll update the above post to reflect that.

Comment: What Python 2.5 folder did you remove? I'm on Lion, and I have Python 2.7 (but maybe I installed that myself).

Comment: I removed the one under /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5

Comment: Hmm, I don't have a Python.framework dir in /Library/Frameworks...

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to install the Universal Binary provided for OS X, see http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.5.4/python-2.5.4-macosx.dmg .

This is well documented on http://docs.python.org/2/using/mac.html.

Comment: Is it ok that it isn't 2.5.6? That was the reason I had balked at dong that.

Comment: Apparently there's no Universal Binary for 2.5.6, the most recent is 2.5.4.

Comment: See the comment on http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.5.6/, "The last binary release of Python 2.5 was 2.5.4."

Comment: Thanks Kenneth. When I try to install that, I get a different error which is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473762/mac-python-installation-step-failed-run-postflight-script

It looks like I've messed things up pretty terribly.

Comment: Ouch. Well, good luck, I guess. Everybody makes mistakes, and you should, it's the best way to learn!

Comment: Got it! (Added above.) No idea if this is a permanent fix though.